# getting an error when trying to find value in database

Tags: c#, database, compiler-errors

So I have a `textbox` and a `button`. I want to enter a value into the `textbox` and it will find the value that i entered in the `row` from the `table` called 'ticket'. I also then want to create a 'rebate slip' `object` in a `table` called 'Rebateslip'. This `table` has 2 fields - an `id` which is autoincremented and the `ticketId` which is the value I entered in the `textbox` (so basically I'm just passing the `ticketId` I just found into the 'RebateSlip' table). I put all the functions in a `class` called 'model' then I call them in the `button` event handler.

```
 public bool rebateslip(int ticketID)
    {
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID FROM ticket WHERE ID = @ticketID", con);
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);

        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ticketID", ticketID);
        var reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        return reader.HasRows;

    }

    public void createRebateslip(int ticketId)
    {
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO RebateSlip (ticketId) VALUES (@ticketId); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();", con);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ticketId", ticketId);
        string insertID = (myCommand.ExecuteScalar()).ToString();
        rebateSlipList.Add(new RebateSlip(Int32.Parse(insertID), ticketId));
    }
```

It works for one number but if I try enter another number into the `textbox` I get the error there is already an open `DataReader` associated with command which must be closed first.
Here's the code for the button.  If the value is found in the table then a 'rebatelip' should be created but that is also not working.

```
 private void buttonPrintRebateSlip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int id;
        if (!int.TryParse(textBoxRebateSlip.Text, out id))
        {
            return;
        }
        if (model.rebateslip(id))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Found ticket");
            //create rebate slip object
            model.createRebateslip(id);
            textBoxRebateSlip.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ticket not in database");
            textBoxRebateSlip.Clear();
        }

    }
```

Comment: where are you using the results of the reader? the error you are getting is correct if you have not disposed or closed the reader variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excerpt from [SqlDataReader.Close Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.close.aspx):

> You must explicitly call the Close method when you are through using
>   the SqlDataReader to use the associated SqlConnection for any other
>   purpose.

You should use the [`using Statement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

```
public bool rebateslip(int ticketID)
{
    using(SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID FROM ticket WHERE ID = @ticketID", con))
    {
        using(SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand))
        {

            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ticketID", ticketID);
            using(var reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                return reader.HasRows;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Anyway, your `sqlDa` SqlDataAdapter makes no sense in the context. Probably you only need:

```
public bool rebateslip(int ticketID)
{
    using(SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID FROM ticket WHERE ID = @ticketID", con))
    {
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ticketID", ticketID);
        using(var reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            return reader.HasRows;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 on a very clean solution this should definitely work for the OP

Answer (score 0):

`reader.close` once you're done with it.

Also -- you should use a `using` or `try...catch` block

Answer (score 0):

This way you never have a reader variable. Still the using paradigm is better.

```
    public bool rebateslip(int ticketID)
    {
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID FROM ticket WHERE ID = @ticketID", con);
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);

        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ticketID", ticketID);
        return myCommand.ExecuteReader().HasRows;
    }

    public void createRebateslip(int ticketId)
    {
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO RebateSlip (ticketId) VALUES (@ticketId); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();", con);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ticketId", ticketId);
        int insertID = (int)myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        rebateSlipList.Add(new RebateSlip(insertID, ticketId));
    }
```

Also it seems you are storing ticketID's in the Insert table (from insertID) and insertID's in the Ticket table (from ticketID). Instead you should use a third table where you store only insertID's and ticketID's, allowing a multiple to multiple relationships while allowing them to be changed/deleted with a single action.

Comment: _This way you never have a reader variable_. That is incorrect. myCommand.ExecuteReader() actually [sends the CommandText to the Connection and builds a SqlDataReader.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx)

Comment: Yes but it's not stored in a variable and I'm hoping that means there's no need to close the reader :P